# How to compile and use libraries with MinGW?

Tags: c++, windows

I am currently trying to use some libraries (specifically libPNG if it helps) for a project, and would like to know how to compile/use/include it using MinGW.

I have not tried anything yet as I am very clueless about this.

edit: I would appreciate if you explain to me as if I were a child, since I am new to this entire thing

Comment: One of the simplest ways is to switch to use msys2 to provide mingw and pull compiled packages using the package manager `pacman` that msys2 uses. [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/) there is quite an extensive list of packages available: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/](https://packages.msys2.org/package/)

Comment: thank you, will try that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest ways of obtaining the binaries for open source libraries compatible with mingw is to switch to use msys2 to provide mingw and pull compiled packages using the package manager pacman that msys2 uses.

The installation of msys2 can be done from here:
https://www.msys2.org/

There is quite an extensive list of packages available:
https://packages.msys2.org/package/

In this list each package shows the pacman command that can be used to install the package for example:
https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-OpenSceneGraph-debug?repo=mingw64

if you look at the installation line you will see

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-OpenSceneGraph-debug
```

this will be the command you type in the msys2 shell to install the debug version of OpenSceneGraph

There is information on how to use pacman with msys2 here:
https://www.msys2.org/docs/package-management/

For more information how to use pacman you can look at the extensive documentation in the ArchLinux distribution: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pacman